# Adb complete failure - start/kill-server doesn't work

Tags: android, macos, shell, android-studio, adb

I'm facing a strange issue with adb in that anything related to adb is failing. Before this is marked as a duplicate, I want to say that I have read a bunch of posts and essentially all of them state that you may need to run `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server`. I have done this and more.

For `adb kill-server` I get the following log:

`cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037: Connection refused`

For `adb start-server` I get:

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: 
/var/folders/_7/rkfglyr552b_ht0cwd140c300000gn/T//adb.501.log
Server had pid: 1977
--- adb starting (pid 1977) ---
adb I 12-18 11:40:26  1977 142946 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge 
version 1.0.39
adb I 12-18 11:40:26  1977 142946 main.cpp:57] Version 27.0.0-4455170
adb I 12-18 11:40:26  1977 142946 main.cpp:57] Installed as 
{mypath}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 12-18 11:40:26  1977 142946 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 12-18 11:40:26  1977 142946 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] 
adb_auth_init...
adb I 12-18 11:40:26  1977 142946 adb_auth_host.cpp:174] read_key_file 
'{mypath}/.android/adbkey'...
adb F 12-18 11:40:26  1977 142958 transport_usb.cpp:37] Check failed: 
usb_packet_size < 4096ULL (usb_packet_size=5120, 4096ULL=4096) 

* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

The main issue is that I cannot run apps on my devices via Android Studio because adb cannot read my devices (both physical devices and emulators).

When I run `adb devices` or some other adb command like...`adb tcpip 5555`, for example, I get the same output that I do for `adb start-server`.

I have also tried:

1. Ensuring all paths to my sdk and adb in my local.properties file, bash_profile, etc. are consistent.
2. Updating Android Studio.
3. Updating all my SDKs/platform-tools/etc via the SDK manager.
4. Uninstalling/reinstalling the sdk via the Android SDK manager.
5. Manually uninstalling the Android SDK and Android Studio and reinstalling.
6. Restarting my devices and my machine.

I have never encountered this issue before and the only thing I did before having this problem was update Android Studio Canary. If anyone has any insight I'd appreciate the input.

**Edit:** I am running the current version of Java and have been since October, I have used adb successfully many times since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in platform-tools 27.0.0. The workaround for this is to downgrade platform tools.

```
cd $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
rm -rf platform-tools/
curl https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.2-darwin.zip -o platform-tools_r26.0.2-darwin.zip
unzip platform-tools_r26.0.2-darwin.zip
rm platform-tools_r26.0.2-darwin.zip
```

There is already [reported bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70244520) in android bug tracker

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you